# Struts2 - I need a sort of EL i think

Tags: struts2, struts

I have a page that must show some divs or some others according to a value from a bean/action.

I mean, somethings like this :

```
*** EL if action.isLogged=true ***
    div 1
*** EL if action.isLogged=false ***
    div 2
```

But on Struts2 I think i can't do these things. How can I do this? Interceptors?

Cheers

**UPDATE**

```
public class UserManager extends ActionSupport {
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    private boolean loggedOn;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // somethings
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getNickname() { return nickname; }
    public void setNickname(String newValue) { nickname=newValue; }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String newValue) { password=newValue; }

    public boolean isLoggedOn() {
        return loggedOn;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE ERROR CODE**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    model.UserManager.checkLogin(UserManager.java:76)
    model.UserManager.execute(UserManager.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Please add model.UserManager class to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using struts2 I would stick to struts2 tags:

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/tag-reference.html

```
<s:if test="%{false}">
   <div>Will Not Be Executed</div>
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="%{true}">
   <div>Will Be Executed</div>
</s:elseif>
<s:else>
   <div>Will Not Be Executed</div>
</s:else>
```

A notable difference is that Struts2 uses OGNL. It is quite easy to use.

I use an interceptor to solve the issue of testing if a user is logged on or not and then letting them get to the required page or directing them to the login screen.

The basic procedure is this:
Create a log in action which places a User object in the session.
Create a log in interceptor that checks if there is a User object in the session, if there is the interceptor will pass execution on, if not it will return "login", there will need to be a global mapping of "login" to the login action... then you're done.  Well you'll of course need to add the login action to that stack that will be used in a package of "secure" actions.

**Edit**: 
Here is how I control if a user sees a "log in" link or a "log out username" link on a page:

```
<s:if test="#session['User']==null">
  <s:a namespace="/public" action="welcome" >Login</s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <s:a namespace="/public" action="logout" >Logout <s:property value="#session['User'].name"/></s:a>
</s:else>
```

An interceptor will help you keep track of what pages need a user to be logged in so you don't check this in every action (in case a non authorized user simply types in the url of a pass word protected page) but it will not help in the rendering.

**Edit:** 
Try the following:

1) The following is the preferred struts2 way for conditionals in your jsp. I tested this against your bean so it works *exactly* as is =)

```
<s:div>
  <s:if test="loggedOn">
    DIV1
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
    DIV2
  </s:else>
</s:div>
```

2) Once your conditional is working perhaps you want more than one jsp to respond if you are logged in... you can't have them log in for every page only to have it forget that you logged in... I suppose you *could* so lets put the fact that you logged in into the session so every jsp in your application can check this...

To do this all you need to do is add the "SessionAware" interface to your Action and your IDE should force you to add the abstract method (a setter) and you'll use that setter to set a session variable... Or more plainly in code:

```
package struts2;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
public class test extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

Now once you have added the "SessionAware" interface so you can set a session field in your class then you can add...

```
public void setLoggedOn(boolean loggedOn) {
    //this.loggedOn = loggedOn;
    session.put("isLoggedOn", true);
}
```

Now in any jsp... you can look into the session variable for the objects that you put into the map...

So we should now be able to change your conditional display to...

```
<s:div>
  <s:if test="#session['isLoggedOn'] == true">
    DIV1
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
    DIV2
  </s:else>
</s:div>
```

Comment: Uhm...in fact i do the Login by using an ajax call, and i don't need to render a "page", just a small zone of that page. Is it possible to do it with interceptor? Thanks for your help

Comment: Interceptors do what actions can they are simply a way to factory out commonality.  Every action travels though quite a number of interceptors by default (the default stack).  Here is how I present either a "Log in" message or a "Log out UserName" message to a user.

Comment: But you put the Bean on session (session scope) or just a variable? (like php). Can you give to me an example of this interceptors?

Comment: Interceptors are a way of factoring code... with the above you can easily put an object into the session and in EVERY action test that variable to determine if you should or should not give access... As soon as you see a situation where you need to add code into each action this is a perfect candidate for an interceptor.  Get the above working and I'll show you how to define an interceptor that will test if a user is logged in and let them access your actions otherwise it will direct them to the log in screen. This way your actions stay as simple as possible.

Comment: Uhm thanks for you help. the problem is that if i get this way, i totally get rid about MODEL in a frameworks that is MVC. Is really not possible to put a bean Scoped Session on Struts2?

Comment: Well... Session aware lets you manipulate the session so that is definitely part of the model.  Your view technology, JSP's in your case but freemarker and velocity are also options.  What you're missing still are the interceptors...  Currently you are testing for 'isLoggedOn' in your view which is bad design when you should be testing this in an interceptor, then all actions which depend on this check are placed in a package governed by this interceptor.  Now this check is in one place and not in either the action or the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [c:if](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) tag

Comment: Uhm...this could work. Just i don't know how to set a name for the bean (in fact, `<c:if test="${UserManager.isLogged}">` doesnt work. Is this the right way to work on Struts2 or is better to set these decision in other ways? (by using the xml file, for example)

Comment: something like this "${property_name}" where property_name will be property in Action class.. Also make sure you have getter and setter for that property

Comment: Uhm, it doesnt work. I put getter and setter for that property, but when i select `<c:if` for example netbeans looks like it doesnt know that tag. Also, i think i need to specify the name of the bean (if i have the property `testProperty` on 2 different beans, how can it know which one select?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a getter on your action called `isLoggedOn()`.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${action.loggedOn}">
        div 1
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        div 2
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

`c:if` works too, but JSTL uses the choose/when/otherwise notation from XSL for its if/else and if/else if/else functionality.

**Updated**:

As I indicated in my code example, you need to use `${action.loggedOn}`. The EL doesn't change based on your action name. Also, use the word `not` instead of the `!`.

Comment: i've the same problem as `c:if` : looks like `<c:choose>` isnt knowed from the JSP page...

Comment: Tried to insert `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> `...but i get `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved`

Comment: Try something like this '<%@ taglib uri="/tags/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>'

Comment: I've restart tomcat and now it found these tags :) Still, the EL doesnt change the div. I add an example above

Comment: Thanks for the Updated. Yeah it works. There is a thing that i can't understand : how can know which parameter from `action`? I cant have many action with the same parameters. Like UserManager with loggedOn and AnotherBean with loggedOn (that do different things).

Comment: You can only have one action per HTTP request. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But when i load the page for the first time, how can Know which action must to be used? There isnt a "default" action. Or, at least, i never seen it :)

Comment: The action to use is determined from the requested URL and what it corresponds to in the struts.xml. By the time the JSP is invoked, the action has already executed. ${action} refers to the action that was invoked and ${action.someProperty} refers to the getSomeProperty method on that action.

Comment: Uhm. Looks at my actual struts.xml : i didnt set a default action. But it get the right now without specify a default bean. How is possible? :)